# AngularJS ng-repeat loading state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm using AngularJS, using ng-repeat to render a list of property listings, which is fetched via json. I also have pagination for the listings, so when you click page 2 for example the app makes a JSON Call, gets new listing data which is then re-rendered by ng-repeat.

My question is how can catch when ng-repeat reloads/re-reneders so i can display a loading gif?

```
$scope.listings = [ { 'title':'listing 1' },{ 'title':'listing 2' }, etc.. ]; 

<div class="listing" ng-repeat="listing in listings">
     <img src="{{listing.img_url}}" />
     {{listing.title}}
</div>

// Listings are updated like this: 
//-------------------------------------------------------
jsonService.searchByPlaceName().success(function(data) {
     $scope.listings = data.response.listings;
});
```

Comment: there seems to be nothing to detect. you yourself control in your code when you reload your `$scope.listings`. so before you do it, show your gif, and once the `success` callback is called, remove the gif.

Comment: You might be able to put a directive on the repeat element, add an image to the elements then detect when the "load" function has been called on enough images. Just a thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the searchByPlaceName method is called, you could attach a loading screen boolean to rootscope and then in the success callback turn it off.

The html might look like

```
<div class="loading" ng-if="loading">
```

where the loading boolean was set to true in the searchByPlaceName method and turned off when it succeeds.